# How do I set an empty search domain on Airport/Time Capsule

Tags: network, time-capsule, internet, airport

My ISP supplies their own search domain via DHCP, which I don't want being passed on to my own devices. However, if you leave the field for 'search domain' empty on an Airpot/Time Capsule it will revert to the ISP default once the text box loses focus. Is it possible to override the value to empty?

Comment: It's ugly but I often put in local since leaving it blank has the obvious downside you mention. Is there any chance you can run DHCP on AirPort/TC and avoid clients getting a response from the ISP. The first thing I do with a modem is get it in bridge mode and turn off everything I can so that the AirPort runs the show for me.

Comment: The TC is running DHCP as far as I know, but I believe it will still pass on some settings from the ISP.

Answer (score 1):

On the AirPort or TimeCapsule that is acting as DHCP and/or NAT, placing a period “.” in the Domain Name field will push a null domain name search to its DHCP clients…

It does this by making yer DHCP clients’ treat hostnames as fully qualified…  That will not disable domain name searches on the DHCP clients if they are configured to use search domains…

BUT, it will eliminate having yer ISP’s domain name appended as an additional domain name search…  With the added benefit of slightly faster DNS resolutions eliminating parent and child domain searches…